# Trouble with running Spyder from Anaconda Python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded and installed Anaconda Python from

http://continuum.io/downloads

Opening the Anaconda Command prompt and typing 'Spyder' as it suggests only results in:

'Spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The command is not `Spyder` but `spyder` (i.e. all letters in lower-case)